# Applying the cdf function to draws from multivariate normal in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Why if I apply the cdf function in Matlab to draws from a multivariate normal distribution I do not get a uniform distribution?

```
P=10000; %number of draws

%% 4 random variables (X,Y,Z,W) jointly distributed as a normal with mean mu:=(muX, muY, muZ, muW)
% and variance sigma:=(sigmaX2 sigmaXY 0 0; sigmaXY sigmaY2 0 0; 0 0 sigmaZ2 sigmaZW; 0 0 sigmaZW sigmaW2)

muX=0.3;
muY=-0.1;
muZ=0.5;
muW=0.2;
sigmaX2=1;
sigmaY2=1;
sigmaZ2=1;
sigmaW2=1;
sigmaXY=-0.7;
sigmaZW=0.6;

mu=[muX, muY, muZ, muW];
sigma=[sigmaX2, sigmaXY, 0, 0; sigmaXY, sigmaY2, 0, 0; 0, 0, sigmaZ2, sigmaZW; 0, 0, sigmaZW, sigmaW2];


%P random draws from the joint distribution of (X,Y,Z,W)
%indep(p,:) is a 1x4 vector representing a draw from the joint distribution of (X,Y,Z,W)
indep = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,P);


%Transform each draw (x,y) of (X,Y) in a draw in [0,1] using cdf(x,y). 
Qindep = mvncdf(indep(:,1:2),[muX, muY],[sigmaX2, sigmaXY; sigmaXY, sigmaY2]);

%Plot the empirical cdf of Qindep
cdfplot(Qindep)
```

The plot is not the cdf of a uniform in [0,1]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I have the feeling you are completelly misunderstanding the fucntion. `mvncdf` does not seem to nedd normally distributed points as an input, instead it uses sample points

Comment: I am not sure, if you try with just the first column of `indep` you'll see that you get a uniform. See this example where I use `mvncdf` and, as an alternative, `ksdendity`. `Q1=ksdensity(indep(:,1), indep(:,1),'function', 'cdf');
Q2 = mvncdf(indep(:,1),muX, sigmaX2);
cdfplot(Q1)
hold on
cdfplot(Q2)`

Comment: What I am thinking now is that, maybe, if we apply the cdf function to a random vector, we don't get a uniform, while, instead,  if we apply the cdf function to a random variable we get a uniform.

Comment: If you look at the example in the documentation, it does not use a random vector, but a meshgrid instead. Generally fucntions do work as described in the documentation: `Rows of the n-by-d matrix X correspond to observations or points, and columns correspond to variables or coordinates. y is an n-by-1 vector.`